# switchIfEmpty is always called

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, reactor

I have a method like this:

```kotlin
fun getActiveVersionWithCacheMiss(type: String): Mono<ActiveVersion> {
        return activeVersionRepository.findByType(type)
                .switchIfEmpty(
                        Mono.defer(return persist(ActiveVersion(type,1)))
                )
    }
```

persist method is a simple method that saves active version:

```kotlin
fun persist(activeVersion: ActiveVersion): Mono<ActiveVersion>{...}
```

In my test I mocked activeVersionRepository to return a simple value for findByType. During debug `activeVersionRepository.findByType(type).block()` evaluates to a value and is definitely not empty.
I'm wondering why despite using defer switchIfEmpty is still called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `return`. The argument of `switchIfEmpty` needs to be evaluated regardless of whether `findByType` emits a value, which means the argument of `defer` needs to be evaluated, and `return` will return out of the entire function `getActiveVersionWithCacheMiss`.

Though I don't see how this code can compile; `return persist(...)` doesn't have a value which `Mono.defer` can use. Do you actually have braces `{}`, not parentheses `()` somewhere?

Comment: When I delete the return before persist() it gives me the following error:              
`Error:(30, 30) Kotlin: Type inference failed: fun <T : Any!> defer(p0: Supplier<out Mono<out T!>!>): Mono<T!>
cannot be applied to
(Mono<ActiveVersion>)`                                                      
And about the second part, I didn't get what you mean by {} or ()

Comment: Something like `Mono.defer { return persist(ActiveVersion(type,1)) }`. I'd guess you actually need `Mono.defer { persist(ActiveVersion(type,1)) }` or `Mono.defer(Supplier<Mono<ActiveVersion>> { persist(ActiveVersion(type,1)) })`.

Comment: As you said replacing parentheses with braces solved it, thanks.